# subprocess выполнение команды в одном потоке

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код и получаю ошибку:

> ```
> zimbra.stdin.write(batch)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stdin'
> ```

```
command_8 = "su zimbra".split()

batch = b"""\
cd /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr deploycrt comm cert.pem chain.pem
zmcontrol restart
exit
"""
zimbra = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S"] + command_8, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          universal_newlines=True).communicate(mypass + '\n')[1]
zimbra.stdin.write(batch)
zimbra.stdin.flush()
result = zimbra.stdout.read()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку в теме исправить можно так

```
"""
zimbra = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S"] + command_8, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          universal_newlines=True)
zimbra.communicate(mypass + '\n')
zimbra.stdin.write(batch)
```

Но communicate убивает процесс. Замени его на stdin.write потом нужно дождаться приглашения шела. Это циклом с read и дальше запускай батник. Но я рекомендовал бы записать все это в файл и запускать батник целиком